# Unique permutations of AAABBBB

Tags: permutations, combinations

Hello lets say I have the string AAABBBB. I don't just want to calculate the numbers want to generate all the unique combinations of this string.

One way I thought of doing it was to simply move each A one position at a time to the end and then move each B one position at a time until the original string was regenerated and remove the duplicates

for example

AAABBBB
AABABBB
AABBABB

etc

but I don't know if this will give me everything or if there is a simpler way that can be generalized.

Can somebody show me a way/if my way is right and help me understand theoretically?

edit: Sorry the title inaccurately said 5 letter than I changed the title because my question is more general.

Comment: "I don't just want to calculate the numbers want to generate all the unique combinations of this string. "  Do you mean that you want to list them all, too?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Well, the five-letter strings formed from letters AAABBBB, will consist of 4B's and one A, or 3B's and two A's, or 2B's and three A's.  In the first case, we count ABBBB, BABBB, BBABB, BBBAB, BBBBA.  In the second case, we count AABBB, BAABB, BBAAB. BBBAA. ABABB. ABBAB, ABBBA, etc... I don't see that your method is going to obtain all such unique five letter strings.  If your title doesn't match your intended question, then please edit it accordingly.

Comment: It would help if you were to give examples of resulting 5-letter strings, resulting from the use of your idea for an approach....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to take out two letters. There are three possibilities: remove two $\sf B$s, or one $\sf A$ and one $\sf B$, or two $\sf A$s. In each one of those cases, we must generate all ways of ordering the remaining letters.

Here is a recursive algorithm. If there are any $\sf A$s at the end of the string, move all of them left till they form a bigger block with an $\sf A$ to their left, then shift that bigger block to the right once. Else, if there is no $\sf A$ at the end of the string, shift the rightmost $\sf A$ one positition right.

If we *hadn't* removed any letters, this would generate the following list:

$$ \begin{array}{l}
\sf \color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}ABBBB \\ 
\sf \color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}ABBB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}ABB\color{Magenta}ABB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}ABBB\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}ABBBB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf \color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}ABBB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}ABB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}ABB\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}ABBB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf \color{LimeGreen}ABB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}ABB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}ABB\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}ABB\color{Orange}ABB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf \color{LimeGreen}ABBB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf \color{LimeGreen}ABBB\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf \color{LimeGreen}ABBBB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline \\ \hline
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}ABBB \\
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}ABB \\
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}ABB\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}ABBB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}ABB \\ 
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}ABB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}ABB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}AB \\ 
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}ABB\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf B\color{LimeGreen}ABBB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline \\ \hline
\sf BB\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}ABB \\
\sf BB\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf BB\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}ABB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf BB\color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf BB\color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf BB\color{LimeGreen}ABB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline \\ \hline
\sf BBB\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}AB \\
\sf BBB\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}AB\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline
\sf BBB\color{LimeGreen}AB\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}A \\ \hline \\ \hline
\sf BBBB\color{LimeGreen}A\color{Orange}A\color{Magenta}A
\\ \end{array}$$

So it looks like this algorithm must be applied to the following seeds:

$$ \begin{array}{l}
\sf AAABB \\
\sf AABBB \\
\sf ABBBB
\end{array} $$

Comment: The OP's question (per title) is to find the unique **5-letter strings** not the number of seven-letter strings.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code (counting from 1):

```
For i in 1 to 5:
    Put an A in position i
    For j in i+1 to 6:
        Put an A in position j
        For k in j+1 to 7:
            Put an A in position k
            Put Bs in all the other positions
            Output the string
```

That shouold give you $35$ results looking like

```
   i j k output
1  1 2 3 AAABBBB
2  1 2 4 AABABBB
3  1 2 5 AABBABB
4  1 2 6 AABBBAB
5  1 2 7 AABBBBA
6  1 3 4 ABAABBB
7  1 3 5 ABABABB
8  1 3 6 ABABBAB
9  1 3 7 ABABBBA
10 1 4 5 ABBAABB
11 1 4 6 ABBABAB
12 1 4 7 ABBABBA
13 1 5 6 ABBBAAB
14 1 5 7 ABBBABA
15 1 6 7 ABBBBAA
16 2 3 4 BAAABBB
17 2 3 5 BAABABB
18 2 3 6 BAABBAB
19 2 3 7 BAABBBA
20 2 4 5 BABAABB
21 2 4 6 BABABAB
22 2 4 7 BABABBA
23 2 5 6 BABBAAB
24 2 5 7 BABBABA
25 2 6 7 BABBBAA
26 3 4 5 BBAAABB
27 3 4 6 BBAABAB
28 3 4 7 BBAABBA
29 3 5 6 BBABAAB
30 3 5 7 BBABABA
31 3 6 7 BBABBAA
32 4 5 6 BBBAAAB
33 4 5 7 BBBAABA
34 4 6 7 BBBABAA
35 5 6 7 BBBBAAA
```